# Parsing Json Data from select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I have a table that has a single `varchar(max)` column called `dbo.JsonData`. It has x number of rows with x number of properties.

How can I create a query that will allow me to turn the result set from a `select *` query into a row/column result set?

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM JSONDATA
FOR JSON Path
```

But it returns a single row of the json data all in a single column:

```
JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
[{"Json_Data":"{\"Serial_Number\":\"12345\",\"Gateway_Uptime\":17,\"Defrost_Cycles\":0,\"Freeze_Cycles\":2304,\"Float_Switch_Raw_ADC\":1328,\"Bin_status\":2304,\"Line_Voltage\":0,\"ADC_Evaporator_Temperature\":0,\"Mem_Sw\":1280,\"Freeze_Timer\":2560,\"Defrost_Timer\":593,\"Water_Flow_Switch\":3328,\"ADC_Mid_Temperature\":2560,\"ADC_Water_Temperature\":0,\"Ambient_Temperature\":71,\"Mid_Temperature\":1259,\"Water_Temperature\":1259,\"Evaporator_Temperature\":1259,\"Ambient_Temperature_Off_Board\":0,\"Ambient_Temperature_On_Board\":0,\"Gateway_Info\":\"{\\\"temp_sensor\\\":0.00,\\\"temp_pcb\\\":82.00,\\\"gw_uptime\\\":17.00,\\\"winc_fw\\\":\\\"19.5.4\\\",\\\"gw_fw_version\\\":\\\"0.0.0\\\",\\\"gw_fw_version_git\\\":\\\"2a75f20-dirty\\\",\\\"gw_sn\\\":\\\"328\\\",\\\"heap_free\\\":11264.00,\\\"gw_sig_csq\\\":0.00,\\\"gw_sig_quality\\\":0.00,\\\"wifi_sig_strength\\\":-63.00,\\\"wifi_resets\\\":0.00}\",\"ADC_Ambient_Temperature\":1120,\"Control_State\":\"Bin Full\",\"Compressor_Runtime\":134215680}"},{"Json_Data":"{\"Serial_Number\":\"12345\",\"Gateway_Uptime\":200,\"Defrost_Cycles\":559,\"Freeze_Cycles\":510,\"Float_Switch_Raw_ADC\":106,\"Bin_status\":0,\"Line_Voltage\":119,\"ADC_Evaporator_Temperature\":123,\"Mem_Sw\":113,\"Freeze_Timer\":0,\"Defrost_Timer\":66,\"Water_Flow_Switch\":3328,\"ADC_Mid_Temperature\":2560,\"ADC_Water_Temperature\":0,\"Ambient_Temperature\":71,\"Mid_Temperature\":1259,\"Water_Temperature\":1259,\"Evaporator_Temperature\":54,\"Ambient_Temperature_Off_Board\":0,\"Ambient_Temperature_On_Board\":0,\"Gateway_Info\":\"{\\\"temp_sensor\\\":0.00,\\\"temp_pcb\\\":82.00,\\\"gw_uptime\\\":199.00,\\\"winc_fw\\\":\\\"19.5.4\\\",\\\"gw_fw_version\\\":\\\"0.0.0\\\",\\\"gw_fw_version_git\\\":\\\"2a75f20-dirty\\\",\\\"gw_sn\\\":\\\"328\\\",\\\"heap_free\\\":10984.00,\\\"gw_sig_csq\\\":0.00,\\\"gw_sig_quality\\\":0.00,\\\"wifi_sig_strength\\\":-60.00,\\\"wifi_resets\\\":0.00}\",\"ADC_Ambient_Temperature\":1120,\"Control_State\":\"Defrost\",\"Compressor_Runtime\":11304}"},{"Json_Data":"{\"Seri...
```

What am I missing?

I can't specify the columns explicitly because the json strings aren't always the same.

This what I expect:

```
Serial_Number   Gateway_Uptime  Defrost_Cycles  Freeze_Cycles   Float_Switch_Raw_ADC    Bin_status  Line_Voltage    ADC_Evaporator_Temperature  Mem_Sw  Freeze_Timer    Defrost_Timer   Water_Flow_Switch   ADC_Mid_Temperature ADC_Water_Temperature   Ambient_Temperature Mid_Temperature Water_Temperature   Evaporator_Temperature  Ambient_Temperature_Off_Board   Ambient_Temperature_On_Board    ADC_Ambient_Temperature Control_State   Compressor_Runtime  temp_sensor temp_pcb    gw_uptime   winc_fw gw_fw_version   gw_fw_version_git   gw_sn   heap_free   gw_sig_csq  gw_sig_quality  wifi_sig_strength   wifi_resets LastModifiedDateUTC Defrost_Cycle_time  Freeze_Cycle_time
12345   251402  540 494 106 0   98  158 113 221 184 0   0   0   1259    1259    1259    33  0   0   0   Freeze  10833   0   78  251402  19.5.4  0.0.0   2a75f20-dirty   328.00000000    10976   0   0   -61 0   2018-03-20 11:15:28.000 0   0
12345   251702  540 494 106 0   98  178 113 517 184 0   0   0   1259    1259    1259    22  0   0   0   Freeze  10838   0   78  251702  19.5.4  0.0.0   2a75f20-dirty   328.00000000    10976   0   0   -62 0   2018-03-20 11:15:42.000 0   0
...
```

Thank you,
Ron

Comment: Using `json path` will obviously gives output in JSON format

Comment: I know that now, but what should I use then?

Comment: Can You please add some sample data and required output.will be much easier to work on solution

Comment: I believe you do not even need to use Json path, as u said data is in nvarchar (max) datatype, you can use string split function to achieve the required output